# calling spring java method using angularJs and ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

could any one please help here to call the spring method **listEmployee** by angularJs ajax method  **ctrlClickHandler**  and should be return result as response any string msg.

there are 3 files:

**1. login.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Login Form Validation</title>
<script>
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", MyCtrl)
 function MyCtrl($scope,$http){
      $scope.attempt = 3;
    $scope.ctrlClickHandler = function(){
        alert("Inside controller: value of myval is " +  $scope.attempt--);
        $scope.username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        $scope.password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        alert($scope.username);
         $http.get("/leavemgmt/getlistEmployee").success(function(data){
            alert(data+"...");
            $scope.Employees=data;
        });  
    }       
};

var globalClickHandler=function globalClickHandler(){
    alert("Inside global click handler ");
}
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app ="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="container">
<div class="main">

<form id="form_id" method="get" name="myform" action="/leavemgmt/getlistEmployee">

<label>User Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<button type="button"  ng-click="ctrlClickHandler()">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. ValidateLogin.java**

```
import com.bean.Employee;
@Controller
public class ValidateLogin{
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
    private DataSource dataSource;
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getlistEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String listEmployee(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String SQL = "select * from employee";
        List <Employee> employees = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(SQL);
        return employees.toString();
    }
}
```

**3. applicationcontext.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
   class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lMS"/>
   <property name = "username" value = "root"/>
   <property name = "password" value = "password"/>
</bean>
<!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
<bean id = "employeeJDBCTemplate"
    class = "controller.ValidateLogin">
   <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />    
</bean>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: angular.js:8560 GET http://localhost:8080/leavemgmt/getlistEmployee 404 (Not Found) @ Ca Phe den

Comment: Where did you configure your `contextPath`? Do you have `web.xml` or something like that for config?

Comment: no man i have only my application.xml file @ Ca Phe Den

Comment: anyone please help to me on above code?  thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you put `leavemgmt` in your request? The problem is in your server-side config, you are querying the wrong url.